# How to solve the equation $- x^4 - 2 x^3 + 14 x^2 - 2 x - 1=0$

Tags: calculus

This equation:

$- x^4 - 2 x^3 + 14 x^2 - 2 x - 1 = 0$

has 4 real solutions (I saw it on GeoGebra), but I can't calculate them analytically.

I know the solving formula of the fourth degree equations (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equazione_di_quarto_grado) :

${\displaystyle x_{1,2}=-{\frac {b}{4a}}-Q\pm {\frac {1}{2}}{\sqrt {-4Q^{2}-2p+{\frac {S}{Q}}}}}$

${\displaystyle x_{3,4}=-{\frac {b}{4a}}+Q\pm {\frac {1}{2}}{\sqrt {-4Q^{2}-2p-{\frac {S}{Q}}}}}$

with

$p={\frac{8ac-3b^{2}}{8a^{2}}}\qquad \qquad {\color {white}.}$

${\displaystyle S={\frac {8a^{2}d-4abc+b^{3}}{8a^{3}}}}$

and

${\displaystyle Q={\frac {1}{2}}{\sqrt {-{\frac {2}{3}}\ p+{\frac {1}{3a}}\left(\Delta _{0}+{\frac {q}{\Delta _{0}}}\right)}}}$

${\displaystyle \Delta _{0}={\sqrt[{3}]{\frac {s+{\sqrt {s^{2}-4q^{3}}}}{2}}}}$

and

${\displaystyle q=12ae-3bd+c^{2}}$

${\displaystyle s=27ad^{2}-72ace+27b^{2}e-9bcd+2c^{3}}$

---

I calculate "q" and comes "196"

I calculate "s" and comes "3760"

But when I try to calculate Δ₀, in the inner root $ \sqrt{s ^ {2} -4q ^ {3}} $ I get a negative value, precisely "- 15980544"

Comment: Alternatively, note that if $a$ is a root of the equation, then so is $1/a$. Therefore, try finding factors of the form $(x-a)(x-1/a)=x^2-bx+1$.

Comment: Yes, you will encounter imaginary numbers. This is inevitable.

Comment: @Trebor but how do I get out of imaginary numbers? In the end I would have 4 real solutions. Are the calculations more complex than I expect?

Comment: If you apply the general formula for quartic equations, there's no way out. (Of course, for specific ones like yours, there may be representations of the roots without imaginary numbers.) This is called *casus irreducibilis*, and involves Galois theory.

Answer (score 3):

First note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
-x^{4}-2x^{3}+14x^{2}-2x-1=0 &\implies& x^{4}+2x^{3}-14x^{2}+2x+1=0\\
&\implies& \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-16=0\\
&\implies& u^{2}+2u-16=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then we have a quadratic equation with solutions $$u=-1\pm\sqrt{17}.$$
Therefore all the solutions are given by
$$x = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1 \pm \sqrt{17} \pm \sqrt{14 - 2 \sqrt{17}}\right).$$

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand how you passed from $x^{4}+2x^{3}-14x^{2}+2x+1=0$ to $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-16=0$

Comment: Your final line isn't quite right. The four solutions are given by $x=(u\pm\sqrt{u^2-4})/2$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4+2x^3-14x^2+2x+1=(x^2+x+1)^2-17x^2=$$
$$\left(x^2-(\sqrt{17}-1)x+1\right)(x^2+(1+\sqrt{17})x+1).$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: It is a bit convoluted solution, I was looking more for a linear solution (metaphorically) that would help me solve other cases like that, that's why I used the solution formula in the question. Or am I wrong and it can also be used in other cases?

Comment: @Kech101: It's not that convoluted. Simply Ferrari's method  for solving quartic equations.